# UICollectionView with 3 cells visible

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview

[image]

I have a view (width: 340, cliptobounds: YES). 
Inside a view, there is a collectionview (width: 300, cliptobounds: NO). 
Collectionview cells (width: same cv width, 300).

If I am on cell A, then I scroll cv to the right (to cell B), cell A invisible. Cell B and C visible.

If I am on cell B, then I scroll cv to the right (to cell C), cell B invisible. Cell C and D visible.

If I am on cell C, then I scroll cv to the left (to cell B), cell C invisible. Cell B and A visible.

So In my screen there is only 2 cells visible.

My question:
How to make 3 cells still visible in screen when I scroll left/right?

Comment: Use 340 width and cliptobounds: YES?

Comment: @Cy-4AH Yes. screenwidth > viewwidth > collectionview